# Run php artisan commands from Cloud Build

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-build

I'm using Cloud Build to deploy my app on Cloud Run. I'd like to set `php artisan` commands in my cloudbuild.yaml to run migrations, init passport library... But I got this error on my Laravel init step:

```
Starting Step #3 - "Laravel Init"
Step #3 - "Laravel Init": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #3 - "Laravel Init": bash: php: command not found
Step #3 - "Laravel Init": bash: line 1: php: command not found
Step #3 - "Laravel Init": bash: line 2: php: command not found
Step #3 - "Laravel Init": bash: line 3: php: command not found
Step #3 - "Laravel Init": bash: line 4: php: command not found
Finished Step #3 - "Laravel Init"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 3 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127
```

And here is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  # Build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
    ...
    id: Build

  # Push the container image to Artifacts Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    ...
    id: Push

  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
    ...

 # Laravel Init
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    id: Laravel Init
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
          php artisan migrate --force
          php artisan db:seed --force
          php artisan db:seed --class=Database\\Seeders\\UsersTableSeeder --force
          php artisan passport:install

images:
  - 'europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/.....'
tags:
  - latest
```

How can I do to execute my php artisan commands ?

Comment: `php` might not be available via that "alias" (i.e. not in your `$PATH`, if that applies here). For example, when I run `which php` locally, I get `/usr/local/path/to/bin/php`, so you might need to use the fully-qualified path to `php`, like `/usr/local/path/to/bin/php artisan migrate --force`, etc.

Comment: @TimLewis Ok I'll try but I don't understand something in Cloud Build. If I add another step and I run the command `ls` it will be executed on my docker container ? Or on the Cloud Run server ? I don't get it. Maybe should I use the name of my image in the last step ?

Comment: I'm afraid my comment was a guess at best; again, I'm not overly familiar with Cloud Build, but I have seen cases where you get that error `php: command not found`. Does Cloud Build have some kind of forum where you can ask questions? Stackoverflow can be good, but only if the correct people are seeing the questions.

Comment: Could you please share more details of your step in your cloudbuild.yaml? Apparently gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud is not reaching your PHP artisan commands. Make sure that the command you are using can be found within your $PATH. Meanwhile you could check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCWGJV3x1Rs) doing something similar and [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/troubleshooting) where you can find some common troubleshootings.

Comment: @OsvaldoLópez The other steps are working it's just build, push, deploy on cloud run. My problem is on the last step and I show all details already. I didn't find gcloud compiler who is able to do `php artisan`. The only way I found for the moment is to use my own image previously built in the first step of my cloudbuild.yaml then go to the /app repo (this is where my code container is located) and `php artisan` cmd works. But I'm searching something better

Comment: Currently, there isn’t any official supported builder that lets you work with PHP artisan.

As a reference, [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders) you can find Google Cloud Build official builder images.

Builders contributed by the public are available in the [Cloud Builders Community repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community).

If you are experiencing an issue with the Cloud Build service or have a feature request, e-mail google-cloud-dev@googlegroups.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I used the helper exec-wrapper. With this helper I can use my laravel container env and connect to Cloud SQL with the embedded cloud sql proxy. So I just have to pass my latest current image previously built in the first step in `cloudbuild.yaml`. I set the database socket connection and then I pass the `migration.sh` file where I can run all my `php artisan` commands.

I'm using mysql so you have to adjust port and connection name if you are using another Database.

cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
  # Build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
    ...
    id: Build

  # Push the container image to Artifacts Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    ...
    id: Push

  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
    ...

 # Laravel Init
  - name: 'gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper'
    id: Laravel Init
    args: [
      '-i', '<YOUR_IMAGE_URL>',
      '-e', 'DB_CONNECTION=mysql',
      '-e', 'DB_SOCKET=/cloudsql/<YOUR_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE>',
      '-e', 'DB_PORT=3306',
      '-e', 'DB_DATABASE=<YOUR_DATABASE_NAME>',
      '-e', 'DB_USERNAME=<YOUR_DB_USER>',
      '-e', 'DB_PASSWORD=<YOUR_DB_PASS>',
      '-s', '<YOUR_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE>',
      '--', '/app/scripts/migration.sh'
    ]
images:
  - 'europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/.....'
```

Care about `/app` folder in `/app/scripts/migration.sh`. `/app` is my `WORKDIR` that I set in my `Dockerfile`

migration.sh look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

php artisan migrate --force
php artisan db:seed --force
#... add more commands
```

Don't forget to Add the permission `Client Cloud SQL` to the Cloud Build service in the IAM section else Cloud Build cannot connect to your Cloud SQL instance.

And care about if your image has an entrypoint file. You have to use `exec $@` to execute the `--` command from app engine exec wrapper. If you don't use it the commands will be ignored.

**Edit**

Now with Laravel 9 we can easily lock the database during the migration with the --`isolated` argument [php artisan migrate --isolated](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#running-migrations).

So we can remove `gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper` step and add the `php artisan migrate --isolated` command into the laravel image (Dockerfile).

Answer (score 0):

Based off this output `php: command not found`, it looks like you don't have PHP installed in your cloud environment

Comment: I'm building the PHP image on the first step. My Dockerfile is `FROM php:7.4.1-apache as base`

Comment: Try the command that this guy runs in his video. He seems to use `sail artisan ...` instead of `php artisan ...` https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx3lE-HPPfh7RhmN298HVEkLasCd5OicSH @John

Comment: The problem is that when I run php artisan from cloud build step, vendor is empty because the command is executed from the github repository, so artisan will not work. I'm stuck