# Should I remove Laravel scheduling in Cloud Run?

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm doing a migration of my Laravel 8 app to Cloud Run. But I have problem with my schedulers. My Laravel app using [Laravel Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) so I got 5 tasks :

```
   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
        $schedule->command(Commands\CmdOne::class)->monthlyOn(1, '02:10');
        $schedule->command(Commands\CmdTwo::class)->dailyAt('04:00');
        $schedule->command(Commands\CmdThree::class)->dailyAt('04:00');
        $schedule->command(Commands\CmdFour::class)->dailyAt('05:00');
        $schedule->command('activations:clean')->daily();
    }
```

But I think it's risky to place the cron inside the container because Cloud Run can run multiple container instances of my app and I fear about to run the tasks multiple times because my tasks send email to my customers and I want to run them just once.

e.g: if Cloud Run create 5 instances of my container at `05:00Am` so the command `$schedule->command(Commands\CmdFour::class)->dailyAt('05:00');` will be executed 5 times and I don't want this.

So I see Google Cloud Scheduler and I can expose a web service to run my tasks. But I don't know if it's the good way ? Or there is another way to execute my tasks ? I don't know if removing Laravel Scheduler is the right way.

So if I'm using Cloud Scheduler now, I have to create 5 crons in Cloud Scheduler. I think it's ok for one application but if I have 10 apps (with the same code base but different Cloud run service) it will be hard to manager all these crons because I'll get 5 crons per apps. So in this case 50 crons.

Do you have a better way to manager this ?

Comment: Cloud Run is a great service. Laravel is a great framework. They are not designed to work together without a lot of bandaids and grief unless your Laravel app is simple and static. There is no simple solution to your scheduling problem. Anything you think up will be complex and hard to both manage and debug. I recommend that you rethink your strategy and use a compute service such as Compute Engine instead. Then scheduling will be easy to implement.

Comment: @JohnHanley Haha you're right. For the moment we have small budget that's why we want to stop Compute Engine and switch to Cloud Run. So for the moment I'll put some bandaids and I keep in mind to switch to Compute Engine later thank you.

Comment: What are you using for the database? That is another complication with Laravel and Cloud Run.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm using Cloud SQL but it's ok. It works well with the DB_SOCKET env var to connect to Cloud SQL instance. And for the migration I'm using Cloud Build to do it in my pipeline https://stackoverflow.com/a/71529687/2519631

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the right cache setup (shared by all servers) then you can use the `onOneServer()` method.

See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-tasks-on-one-server

Comment: That is a good suggestion. However, since the OP is going from Compute Engine to Cloud Run to save money, by the time he adds up Redis and Cloud SQL, he will find it cheaper to stay on Compute Engine.

Comment: Very nice ! I think it's a good solution I'll see that thank you